# Non-blocking array reduce in NodeJS?

Tags: arrays, node.js, nonblocking

I have a function that takes in two very large arrays.  Essentially, I am matching up orders with items that are in a warehouse available to fulfill that order.  The order is an object that contains a sub array of objects of order items.

Currently I am using a reduce function to loop through the orders, then another reduce function to loop through the items in each order.  Inside this nested reduce, I am doing a filter on items a customer returned so as not to give the customer a replacement with the item they just send back.  I am then filtering the large array of available items to match them to the order.  The large array of items is mutable since I need to mark an item used and not assign it to another item.

Here's some psudocode of what I am doing.

```
orders.reduce(accum, currentOrder)

{
   currentOrder.items.reduce(internalAccum, currentItem)

   {
       const prevItems = prevOrders.filter(po => po.customerId === currentOrder.customerId;
       const availItems = staticItems.filter(si => si.itemId === currentItem.itemId && !prevItems.includes(currentItem.labelId)
        // Logic to assign the item to the order

   }
}
```

All of this is running in a MESOS cluster on my server.  The issue I am having is that my MESOS system is doing a health check every 10 seconds.  During this working of the code, the server will stop responding for a short period of time (up to 45 seconds or so).  The health check will kill the container after 3 failed attempts.

I am needing to find some way to do this complex looping without blocking the response of the health check.  I have tried moving everything to a eachSerial using the [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) library but it still locks up.  I have to do the work in order or I would have done something like async.each or async.eachLimit, but if not processed in order, then items might be assigned the same thing simultaneously.

Comment: If the code you posted is the code you have in your file: that's not proper code in the slightest. It _might_ run, but it certainly won't do what you suggest it should be doing. I've added some newlines to show what the actual interpretation is, namely a reduce call, then another reduce call, and then a single pass that sets two consts. That said, if you're doing a reduce inside a reduce, that's kind of weird... can you instead explain what data you have (structurally. The actual values don't need to be "real", but the props/etc need to represent your setup) what you want that data to become?

Comment: Sounds like your system is actually just doing work, in which case there's no problem with seeing a heavy load.  I don't know anything about MESOS... can you simply change the priority on your Node.js task in the container so that whatever other healthcheck application runs can have some CPU too?

Comment: That takes 45 seconds to execute synchronously? Looping asynchronously won't be your solution in that case, that might bump the runtime up to several dozen minutes. Put it on another thread that's not handling incoming traffic.

Comment: Alternatively, this might be a use-case for a [C++ addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

Comment: You won't be able to do this using reduce. You could perform the work in "batches" (e.g. only process N orders at a time) and queue up each batch using `setTimeout` or `setImmediate` which would allow other things to execute during the long processing time. This would increase the processing time, but processing performance was not one of your concerns so that may be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do batch processing here with a promisified setImmediate so that incoming events can have a chance to execute between batches. This solution requires async/await support.

```
async function batchReduce(list, limit, reduceFn, initial) {
    let result = initial;

    let offset = 0;

    while (offset < list.length) {
        const batchSize = Math.min(limit, list.length - offset);
        for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
            result = reduceFn(result, list[offset + i]);
        }
        offset += batchSize;
        await new Promise(setImmediate);
    }

    return result;
}
```